# JSF(primefaces) SelectOneMenu does not set value in bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

primefaces selectOneMenu dont save value, when in '' custom objects, when here simple objects as String,Double,Integer it works correctly:

```
     <ui:define name="body-content">
    <p:panel id="filtePanel">
        <c:forEach items="#{journalCall.filterPanel.filterList}" var="filter">
            <h:form class="form-inline" style="display:flex;">
                <p:panel styleClass="form-group" style="white-space: nowrap">
                    <p:selectOneMenu styleClass="form-control" value="#{filter.definition}">
                        <f:selectItem noSelectionOption="true" itemLabel="Выбор фильтра"/>
                        <f:selectItems value="#{journalCall.filterPanel.availableFields}" var="field"
                                       itemLabel="#{field.caption}"
                                       itemValue="#{field}"/>
                        <p:ajax event="change" update="@this :filtePanel"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </p:panel>
            </h:form>
        </c:forEach>
    </p:panel>
    <h:form styleClass="container">
        <p:commandButton value="Добавить фильтр" actionListener="#{journalCall.filterPanel.addPanel}"
                         update=":filtePanel"
                         styleClass="btn-primary"/>
        <ui:insert name="search"/>
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

JournalCall is @SessionScoped @ManagedBean
I`m try to use converter,default jsf selectOneMenu no result...

bean code :

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean
public class JournalCall implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Inject
@FilterPanelQualified(form = FilterForm.JOURNAL_CALL)
private FilterPanel filterPanel;

public FilterPanel getFilterPanel() {
    return filterPanel;
   }
}
```

FilterFieldDefinition class (FilterFieldType is enum):

```
public class FilterFieldDefinition {

private  String name;
private  FilterFieldType fieldType;
private  String caption;

public FilterFieldDefinition(String name, FilterFieldType fieldType,
        String caption) {
    this.setName(name);
    this.setFieldType(fieldType);
    this.setCaption(caption);
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public FilterFieldType getFieldType() {
    return fieldType;
}

public void setFieldType(FilterFieldType fieldType) {
    this.fieldType = fieldType;
}

public String getCaption() {
    return caption;
}

public void setCaption(String caption) {
    this.caption = caption;
  }
 }

@Override
public List<FilterFieldDefinition> getAvailableFields() {
    return (metadata);
}
```

f:selectItems value is

```
 public List<FilterFieldDefinition> metadata;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
 ....
 }
    @Override
public List<FilterFieldDefinition> getAvailableFields() {
    return (metadata);
}
```

getFilterList() instance :

```
public class FilterCondition {

private String textValue;
private Date dateFrom;
private Date dateTo;
private String secondTextValue;
private String panelID;
private FilterFieldDefinition definition;
private FilterOperation operation;

public String getTextValue() {
    return textValue;
}

public void setTextValue(String textValue) {
    this.textValue = textValue;
}

public Date getDateFrom() {
    return dateFrom;
}

public void setDateFrom(Date dateFrom) {
    this.dateFrom = dateFrom;
}

public Date getDateTo() {
    return dateTo;
}

public void setDateTo(Date dateTo) {
    this.dateTo = dateTo;
}

public String getSecondTextValue() {
    return secondTextValue;
}

public void setSecondTextValue(String secondTextValue) {
    this.secondTextValue = secondTextValue;
}

public String getPanelID() {
    return panelID;
}

public void setPanelID(String panelID) {
    this.panelID = panelID;
}

public FilterOperation getOperation() {
    return operation;
}

public void setOperation(FilterOperation operation) {
    this.operation = operation;
}

public FilterFieldDefinition getDefinition() {
    return definition;
}

public void setDefinition(FilterFieldDefinition definition) {
    this.definition = definition;
}
}
```

Converter :

```
  @FacesConverter(forClass = FilterFieldDefinition.class,value =    "simpleConverter")
 public class SimpleConverter implements Converter {

@Inject
@FilterPanelQualified(form = FilterForm.JOURNAL_CALL)
private FilterPanel filterPanel;

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }

    for (FilterFieldDefinition filterFieldDefinition : filterPanel.getAvailableFields()) {
        if (filterFieldDefinition.getCaption().equals(value)) {
            return filterFieldDefinition;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    if (value == null) {
        return "";
    }
    if (value instanceof FilterFieldDefinition) {
        return String.valueOf(((FilterFieldDefinition) value).getCaption());
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

set converter:

```
      <h:selectOneMenu styleClass="form-control" value="#{filter.definition}" immediate="true" converter="simpleConverter">
```

Comment: You need to include your backing bean code, most the time when this doesn't work it's due to a malformed setter/getter. JSF is expecting setter/getters to adhere to java coding standards.

Comment: @PatrickJAbareII every bean has gettter\setter

Comment: Each object in your `getFilterList()` should have a getter/setter for `definition`. Your provided code doesn't list the `getFilterList()` nor the getter/setter for `definition`.

Comment: @PatrickJAbareII  <p:selectOneMenu styleClass="form-control" value="#{filter.definition}">     'filter' instance of FilterCondition and here getter and setter

Comment: Hmm looks correct then. Have you used `<af:selectItem` in conjunction with `<af:selectItems` before? I wasn't aware they could be stacked.

Comment: @PatrickJAbareII yes, i`am used item '<f:selectItem>' with '<f:selectItems>' and it works correct.

Comment: I don't see problem. If no one else does, I would start over, George. PrimeFaces `selectOneMenu` does work, so something you've introduced breaks it. Start with a small, _working_ example, and add changes, smallest to largest, until you can reproduce the problem with a single change.

Comment: @BalusC primefaces version 5.1, changed '<c:forEach>' to '<ui:repeat>' not working (

Comment: I asked for JSF impl and version, not for PF version. E.g. "Mojarra 2.2.11" or "MyFaces 2.2.8".

Comment: @DavidS 'selectOneMenu' perfect works with simple objects, but when i`m insert there custom object state don`t saved

Comment: @BalusC  Mojarra 2.2.8-jbossorg-1

Comment: That sounds important, @GeorgeVassilev. You should include that in the description.

Comment: Wait .. You should have gotten a conversion error (at least in server log). Why didn't you search/tell about that immediately?

Comment: @BalusC i checked server log, all clear no conversion errors there

Comment: @BalusC i`am try to use converter and learn all themes about my problem on SO.  In ajax listener '( ((HtmlSelectOneMenu) ajaxBehaviorEvent.getSource()).getValue())' return  always null